Find upper bound of convergence rate of sequence under recurrence relation
Let $x_0 > 1$, $a, b \in (0, 1],$ and $c > 0,$ and define a sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ as follows: $$
    x_{n+1} = x_n - c (x_n^a - 1)(x_n^b - 1).
$$ Assume that $c$ is small enough (depending on $x_0$) that $x_{n+1} > 1$ whenever $x_n > 1.$ My question is: how can I show that the sequence $x_n$ converges to $1$, and how can I derive an upper bound for the rate of convergence? I.e. I want a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) = 0$ and $x_n - 1 \leq f(n)$.
What I tried: We can consider the continuous relaxation (i.e. ODE) of this discrete recursion: $$
    y' = -c(y^a-1)(y^b-1),
$$ which is separable, but the solution requires integrating some terms that don't have a closed form antiderivative.
I also tried upper bounding $x_{n+1} - x_n$ by lower bounding $(x^a-1)(x^b-1)$. For example, if we had some $d$ for which $(x^a-1)(x^b-1) \geq (x-1)^d,$ then we would also have $$
    x_{n+1} \leq x_n - c(x_n-1)^d,
$$ so $$
    x_{n+1} - 1 \leq (x_n - 1) - c(x_n-1)^d,
$$ and we could use some standard techniques to derive a convergence rate of $y_n = x_n - 1$. However, I had trouble finding such a $d$, and I'm not sure if we can choose a $d$ that works for every possible value of $x$. Perhaps we could choose $d$ based on $x_0$?
Any help is appreciated.
